# Increment declared integer variable

Tags: twig

I try to do zebra striping:

```
{% set counter = 0 %}
{% for entity in entities %}
  <tr class="{{ cycle(['odd', 'even'], counter) }}">
    {% counter++ %}
```

but I am getting error:

> Unexpected tag name "counter" (expecting closing tag for the "for" tag
>   defined near line 11)

Could somebody give me solution?

**[EDIT]**

My bad solution is so easy:

```
{% set counter = counter + 1 %}
```

Comment: Is this for a table? `<table class="table tabled-striped">`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There's an easier way to do what you want:

```
{{ cycle(["even", "odd"], loop.index) }}
```

See the [docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) for the `loop` goodies.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have full control over the html, you can try this:

```
{% if loop.index is divisibleby(2) %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

You can read it here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/divisibleby.html

note that `loop.index` is used 'as-is', it does not refer to a variable rather the hidden indexing of the for loop.